# How to remove a polyline that is created on another method

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

I want the polyline that is already created on another method to be removed. Is there a way to remove that specific polyline? Below is my codes for adding polyline.

```
public void lardizabalToTayuman() {
map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(
                new LatLng(14.617071, 120.989945),
                new LatLng(14.605693, 121.000863),
                new LatLng(14.605599, 121.000939),
                new LatLng(14.603097, 121.001786),
                new LatLng(14.602900, 121.001089),
                new LatLng(14.605246, 121.000252),
                new LatLng(14.613429, 120.992410),
                new LatLng(14.611934, 120.990768),
                new LatLng(14.617094, 120.985795)
                )
                        .width(5)
                        .color(Color.RED)

        );
}
```

My onMapReady codes:

```
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        LatLng manila = new LatLng(14.5995, 120.9842);
        MarkerOptions option = new MarkerOptions();
        option.position(manila).title("Manila");
        map.addMarker(option);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(manila));
        lardizabalToTayuman();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the reference of the `Polyline` and just call .remove(), it will remove the polyline.

Exp :

```
 Polyline myPolyline = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(
                new LatLng(14.617071, 120.989945),..
                ));
```

and while removing just call `myPolyline.remove();`

Note :

> Added `Polyline myPolyline` as a global variable, So that you can
>   access in other methods.

Edited :

In you case you can do like this,

```
private Polyline myPolyline;

public void lardizabalToTayuman() {
   myPolyline = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(
                new LatLng(14.617071, 120.989945),
                new LatLng(14.605693, 121.000863),
                new LatLng(14.605599, 121.000939),
                new LatLng(14.603097, 121.001786),
                new LatLng(14.602900, 121.001089),
                new LatLng(14.605246, 121.000252),
                new LatLng(14.613429, 120.992410),
                new LatLng(14.611934, 120.990768),
                new LatLng(14.617094, 120.985795)
                )
                        .width(5)
                        .color(Color.RED)

        );
}
```

When you want to remove just call this method,

```
private void removeLardizabalToTayuman() {
    if(myPolyline != null) {
       myPolyline.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, sorry for posting a question that is not yet finished. My friend clicked post before letting me finish.

Comment: Thanks! What we needed. Accept answer later.